# Is Araucaria fruit toxic?

Tags: botany, toxicology, fruit

I've had an Araucaria tree in my garden for more than 30 years.
Today a fruit fell off the tree. It looks just like this one:

[image: Araucaria fruit]

I want to know if it is toxic?

Can I eat it? If so, how?

Comment: A very simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=araucaria+edible) should have told you that the seeds are edible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Araucaria araucana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araucaria_araucana)* is an evergreen. The pictured "fruit" is actually more of a cone (which I don't think you'd want to eat). However, the seeds are edible, and look like this:

[image: Araucaria seeds]

Let the cone dry and it should open up.